# Android JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I have a layout which asks the user to input name and date.For inputting date I use https://github.com/ErNaveen/MaterialDateTimePicker library and also use OkHttpLibrary for sending data to server.When I clicked the submit button after inputting both data, I get the following error. Scoping for a response...

Error:

```
12-01 12:38:28.664 10516-10575/com.root5solutions.numerology W/OpenGLRenderer: Layer exceeds max. dimensions supported by the GPU (720x5903, max=4096x4096)
12-01 12:38:28.674 10516-10575/com.root5solutions.numerology D/OpenGLRenderer: Current memory usage / total memory usage (bytes):
                                                                                 TextureCache         23040000 / 25165824
                                                                                 LayerCache                  0 / 16777216 (numLayers = 0)
                                                                                 Layers total          0 (numLayers = 0)
                                                                                 RenderBufferCache           0 /  2097152
                                                                                 GradientCache               0 /   524288
                                                                                 PathCache                   0 / 10485760
                                                                                 TessellationCache           0 /  1048576
                                                                                 TextDropShadowCache         0 /  2097152
                                                                                 PatchCache                  0 /   131072
                                                                                 FontRenderer 0 A8           0 /        0
                                                                                 FontRenderer 0 RGBA         0 /        0
                                                                                 FontRenderer 0 total        0 /        0
                                                                               Other:
                                                                                 FboCache                    0 /        0
                                                                               Total memory usage:
                                                                                 23040000 bytes, 21.97 MB
12-01 12:38:28.744 10516-10516/com.root5solutions.numerology A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI CallVoidMethodV called with pending exception 'java.lang.IllegalStateException' thrown in void android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(long, int):-2
12-01 12:38:28.744 10516-10516/com.root5solutions.numerology A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]     in call to CallVoidMethodV
12-01 12:38:28.744 10516-10516/com.root5solutions.numerology A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]     from void android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(long, int)
12-01 12:38:28.744 10516-10516/com.root5solutions.numerology A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65] "main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable
12-01 12:38:28.744 10516-10516/com.root5solutions.numerology A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x75c89f48 self=0xb75216c0
12-01 12:38:28.744 10516-10516/com.root5solutions.numerology A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | sysTid=10516 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb6f51bec
12-01 12:38:28.754 10516-10516/com.root5solutions.numerology A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | state=R schedstat=( 1634630802 80959774 580 ) utm=153 stm=10 core=2 HZ=100
12-01 12:38:28.754 10516-10516/com.root5solutions.numerology A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | stack=0xbe3a6000-0xbe3a8000 stackSize=8MB
12-01 12:38:28.754 10516-10516/com.root5solutions.numerology A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
12-01 12:38:28.754 10516-10516/com.root5solutions.numerology A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #00 pc 000047e0  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (_ZN13UnwindCurrent6UnwindEjP8ucontext+23)
12-01 12:38:28.754 10516-10516/com.root5solutions.numerology A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #01 pc 00002ff9  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (_ZN9Backtrace6UnwindEjP8ucontext+8)
12-01 12:38:28.754 10516-10516/com.root5solutions.numerology A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #02 pc 00257949  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiPKcPNS_6mirror9ArtMethodE+68)
12-01 12:38:28.754 10516-10516/com.root5solutions.numerology A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #03 pc 0023b869  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEE+144)
12-01 12:38:28.754 10516-10516/com.root5solutions.numerology A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #04 pc 000b50a3  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3artL8JniAbortEPKcS1_+582)
12-01 12:38:28.754 10516-10516/com.root5solutions.numerology A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #05 pc 000b57d9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9JniAbortFEPKcS1_z+60)
12-01 12:38:28.754 10516-10516/com.root5solutions.numerology A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #06 pc 000b8917  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheckC2EP7_JNIEnviPKc+1286)
12-01 12:38:28.754 10516-10516/com.root5solutions.numerology A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #07 pc 000bfdaf  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8CheckJNI15CallVoidMethodVEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectP10_jmethodIDSt9__va_list+30)
12-01 12:38:28.754 10516-10516/com.root5solutions.numerology A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #08 pc 00063fdb  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (???)
12-01 12:38:28.754 10516-10516/com.root5solutions.numerology A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #09 pc 00077e99  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android26NativeDisplayEventReceiver13dispatchVsyncExij+40)
12-01 12:38:28.754 10516-10516/com.root5solutions.numerology A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #10 pc 00078061  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android26NativeDisplayEventReceiver11handleEventEiiPv+80)
12-01 12:38:28.754 10516-10516/com.root5solutions.numerology A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #11 pc 0001132b  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper9pollInnerEi+482)
12-01 12:38:28.754 10516-10516/com.root5solutions.numerology A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #12 pc 000113d5  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper8pollOnceEiPiS1_PPv+92)
12-01 12:38:28.754 10516-10516/com.root5solutions.numerology A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #13 pc 00083a75  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android18NativeMessageQueue8pollOnceEP7_JNIEnvi+22)
12-01 12:38:28.754 10516-10516/com.root5solutions.numerology A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #14 pc 000b61bb  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (Java_android_os_MessageQueue_nativePollOnce__JI+102)
12-01 12:38:28.754 10516-10516/com.root5solutions.numerology A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native method)
12-01 12:38:28.754 10516-10516/com.root5solutions.numerology A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
12-01 12:38:28.754 10516-10516/com.root5solutions.numerology A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:122)
12-01 12:38:28.754 10516-10516/com.root5solutions.numerology A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5930)
12-01 12:38:28.754 10516-10516/com.root5solutions.numerology A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(Native method)
12-01 12:38:28.754 10516-10516/com.root5solutions.numerology A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
12-01 12:38:28.754 10516-10516/com.root5solutions.numerology A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
12-01 12:38:28.754 10516-10516/com.root5solutions.numerology A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
12-01 12:38:28.754 10516-10516/com.root5solutions.numerology A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65] 
12-01 12:38:28.954 10516-10516/com.root5solutions.numerology A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 10516 (ions.numerology)
```

Comment: which support library version you are using? and library?

Comment: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0

Comment: try to downgrade support version to 22.0.0 for all support libraries. `appcompat, support, recyclerview, design, cardview` only if you are using these.

Comment: Could you tell me what caused that error.It is recently I have encountered such an error. I have run previously with the same version but no error has been found..

Comment: have you tried downgrade version? let me know if you're able to reproduce error again. if not then i will post reason to accept answer

Comment: What about compledsdkversion and buildtools version

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160260/discussion-between-aks4125-and-jobin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this library [Updated as on Nov'11](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker) instead of library which you are using.
it seems that error is related to enter/exit animation and I suggest instead of making changes in older library, you should go for newer updated library.

P.S last commit was 3 years ago in library which you have mentioned.